# How to setup a daemon on the Laravel Vapor platform?

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge, laravel-vapor

So, I have a node.js script which I run as a daemon on Laravel Forge.

[image]

Now, I'd like to migrate it over to Laravel Vapor platform. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I am in same situation. Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your script does but this does not seem possible at this time, as vapor is not designed like that. We wanted to spin up a rabbitmq service and you have to run the command 'php artisan rabbitmq:consume' with a daemon to constantly process the queue.

The only viable option I have found was to deploy the code to a EC2 instance as well and that runs the 'php artisan rabbitmq:consume' command only to process the queue.

It would spin up a separate EC2 instance for WebSocket server and everything like that. But for simple scripts that need to run, I do agree vapor needs to add something like that.

Maybe you could add your node script as a separate lambda function, maybe.